# Expression not assignable error

Tags: ios, syntax-error, null

I am getting an 'Expression is not assignable' error while assigning nil value. Following is the code.

```
-(void)connect{
   RTMPCLient *socket = [[RTMPClient alloc] init];
   NSMutableDictionary *stream = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:socket forKey:@"1"];
}
-(void)disconnect{
   [stream objectForKey:@"1"] = nil; //error on this line
}
```

I want to assign nil to the socket object without storing it another variable. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `NSArray` or a `NSDictionary` can't contain an empty value... You can use `[NSNull null]`.
But I recommend you to delete this object instead of putting nil...

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong method. Use

```
[stream  setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:@"1"]
```

or

```
stream[@"1"] = [NSNull null]
```

Comment: I tried it...some how I want make the retain count=0. Don't know how

Comment: An old object will be released here

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but, why don't you use

[stream removeObjectForKey:@"1"];

Comment: After removing it from stream, dealloc socket. That should do it.

Comment: Yes, that can be done but I how can I refer to that object as many instances with the same name will be created ?

Comment: Why do you say that there are many instances with the same name are created?

Comment: Each instance of RTMPClient is one connection. There are multiple connections being made with the same name 'socket' but there are initialized multiple times so multiple instances.